# Is there a path property in the SaveFileDialog tool?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
string path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
bool ans = saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists;
```

I want to save a path of a picture in a data base.
I used saveFileDialog- its great but I dont have the path property- only 
Check Path Exist which does not help me.
I tried also the folder Browser Dialog which is great and has Selected Path
property- but its only for folders, not pictures. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_FileName) property:

> The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").

I'm slightly unclear what your question is about though - if you're trying to select an *existing* file so that you can save your path in the database, you want [`OpenFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8) instead. `SaveFileDialog` is when you're trying to save existing content into a new file (or replacing an existing file). If your question meant "I have image content in the database, and I want to save that into the file system" then `SaveFileDialog` is fine.

The property you want in `OpenFileDialog` for the selected file is also `FileName`, by the way.